# how to merge two arrays (array 1d and array 2d) into a object using lodash

Tags: javascript, lodash

I am looking for best ways of doing this. I have two arrays (array 1d and array 2d):

```js
key = [1,2,3];
value = [['a','b','c'], ['d','e','f'], ['g','h','i']]
```

The end result I want is an array of map:

```js
[{1:a,2:b,3:c},{1:d,2:e,3:f},{1:g,2:h,3:i}]
```

How do I do it the most efficient/clean way using lodash? Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Map the values array, and use `_.zipObject()` to combine the with the keys with the keys:

```js
const keys = [1,2,3];
const values = [['a','b','c'], ['d','e','f'], ['g','h','i']]

const result = values.map(v => _.zipObject(keys, v))

console.log(result)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.15/lodash.js"></script>
```

If you use lodash/fp you can generate a function with `_.flow()` that curries `_.zipObject()` with the `keys`, and passes it to `_.map()`. Now you can call the function with the `values` to get an array of objects:

```js
const fn = _.flow(_.zipObject, _.map)

const keys = [1,2,3];
const values = [['a','b','c'], ['d','e','f'], ['g','h','i']]

const result = fn(keys)(values)

console.log(result)
```

```html
<script src='https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/g/lodash@4(lodash.min.js+lodash.fp.min.js)'></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

A plain Javascript version with [`Object.fromEntries`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/fromEntries).

```js
const
    keys = [1, 2, 3],
    values = [['a', 'b', 'c'], ['d', 'e', 'f'], ['g', 'h', 'i']],
    result = values.map(array => Object.fromEntries(keys.map((k, i) => [k, array[i]])));

console.log(result)
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```